# How to place a button in each row of table in django management form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

In my Django application, I have a form with Parent/Child model objects laid out using loop. To dynamically add child form instances, I am using Django [dynamic formset](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset).

Every thing works fine including saving of user inputs without hassle. So far, so good.

However, now my user wants that **I place one button** before a particular field (`spl_instructions`) in each of the dynamically rendered rows (of fields). The instant field `spl_instructions` (of the child table) is a `CharField` of 255 chracters and is being rendered as `Textarea` in the page. The "button" is intended to be used to open the field `spl_instructions` if and when there is a need to enter text in the field. This route is being taken to **conserve** space.

### models.py

```
class ProductAssy(models.Model):
    prod_assy_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, ...)
    prod_assy_num = models.CharField(max_length=24, ...)
    prod_assy_type = models.ForeignKey(MaterialType, ...)
    short_text = models.CharField(max_length=55, verbose_name="Description")
    # ... Rest of the fields

class BillOfMatlItems(models.Model):
    bom_item_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, ...)
    prod_assy_id = models.ForeignKey(ProductAssy, ...)
    short_text = models.CharField(max_length=55, verbose_name="Description")
    spl_instructions = models.CharField(max_length=255, ...)
    # ... Rest of the fields
```

### forms.py

```
class CreateProdAssyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductAssy
        fields = (...)

class CreateAssyBomForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BillOfMatlItems
        fields = (...)

        widgets = {
            'short_text': forms.TextInput(attrs={'style': 'width:300px; text-align:right;'}),
            # ...
            # The Button needs to be placed HERE
            'spl_instructions': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':4, 'cols':35, 'placeholder': 'type spl inst'}),
            }

        exclude = ()
```

### Template

```
...
    <table id="...>
        {{ bill_of_matl_list.management_form }}
        {% for form in bill_of_matl_list.forms %}
            ...
            {{ form.non_field_errors }}         
            {% if forloop.first %}
                <thead id="...>
                <tr>
                    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                        <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
                </thead>
            {% endif %}    
            <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %} formset_row"> 
                {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                    ...
                    <td>
                        {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                        {{ field }}
                    </td>    
                    ...
                {% endfor %}                    
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
...
```

Partial image of the page with fields and the column where the button is needed is shown below (**please note** that, an image of button "**Open Pad**" has been placed in the image **where an actual button is needed**):

[image]

**My question is: How can a button be placed in the column before the field 'spl_instructions' (`Textarea` )?**

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition in your loop where you render the form:

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    ...
    <td>
        {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
        {% if field.id == 'id_spl_instructions' %}
            <button>Button</button>
        {% endif %}
        {{ field }}
    </td>    
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Have you tried this? What is this supposed to be doing??